# Android bluetooth sends data swapped when writing after long pause

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

My app is sending some data via bluetooth socket using Serial Port Profile, and the other device is Microchip's BM78 module.

Everything is working fine except one very particular case when testing with Huawei NEM-L21 phone. The data delivered correctly right after connection is made, or if data frames are sent frequently. But if there's a pause of 5-10 seconds between transfers, then the next transfer will get the beginning of the data blob altered. The first two blocks of approximately 650 bytes each is swapped, like if it was buffered before sending, and the second buffer gets transferred before the first one. The rest of the blob is ok.

I have no explanation for that. I've excluded BM78 issues, it's working totally ok with windows (virtual com port for bluetooth), and with a bunch of other android devices. It's only this particular phone that shows this issue.

So, is that just a bug in the phone's firmware, or there's something about bluetooth that's missed my attention? Like maybe power management options I can tweak in the phone? Anything related to Bluetooth in general?